# Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 stopped working in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, laptop

I tried a lot of different things and i think now my wifi is really screwed up. Here is some info that may help.

```
dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[   13.148519] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode failed with error -2
[   13.514569] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   14.180253] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[   14.180590] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   14.181088] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[   14.181114] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   19.180492] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[   19.180497] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[   19.180505] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   19.180931] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   19.181008] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you still have this issue? If so, please review [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and then [edit] your post to provide necessary information for troubleshooting. If not, please let us know that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your dmesg output shows that your wifi is blocked by rfkill (line 5).  To turn it back on, try `sudo rfkill unblock all`.